# .htaccess file blocking IP addresses from an external file

Tags: wordpress

In the Wordpress .htaccess file, I have to block access to a large number of IP addresses, many of them are single addresses, so it is not possible to block the entire pool of addresses. I want to keep the addresses to be blocked in a separate file.
How to load (refer to) another file.

```
Order Deny, Allow
Deny from 1.1.1.1
Deny from 2.2.2.2
Deny from 3.3.3.3
Deny from 4.4.4.4
............
subsequent IP addresses read from the loaded file
............
Allow from All
```

Comment: See the answer to this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13008242/ban-ips-from-text-file-using-htaccess , or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10738320/apache-deny-from-list-of-ips-in-external-file